# JS if condition failing to compare to regex capture group

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to replace l and 1 with "lith", m and 2 with "meso", n and 3 with "neo" and a and 4 with "axi" (as you can see below). Thing is i have 2 capture groups due to the variable structure of the "command" so i have to check both groups for the result (one result is always `undefined` and the other is either a letter, a word or a number). However it only works for the first if-condition and fails to return anything for the later 3. what am i missing here?

code snippet:

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^re:([lmna1234]|lith|meso|neo|axi)\/|e:([lmna1234]|lith|meso|neo|axi)r\//gi, function (full_match, $1, $3) {
            console.log(`var0: ${full_match}, var1: ${$1}, var3: ${$3}`);
            if ($1 in ["lith", "l", 1] || $3 in ["lith", "l", 1]) {
                era = "lith"
            } else if ($1 in ["meso", "m", 2] || $3 in ["meso", "m", 2]) {
                era = "meso"
            } else if ($1 in ["neo", "n", 3] || $3 in ["neo", "n", 3]) {
                era = "neo"
            } else if ($1 in ["axi", "a", 4] || $3 in ["axi", "a", 4]) {
                era = "axi"
            }
            return `relic/era:${era}/`
}));
```

input: `re:2/`

expected output: `relic/era:meso/`

output: `relic/era:undefined/`

Comment: Maybe the first condition is always true? BTW: add a [mcve].

Comment: `$1 in ["lith", "l", 1]` will check if `$1` is either 0, 1 or 2. You need to check `["lith", "l", "1"].includes($1)`. Your question is unclear. Can you post some samples of input and expected output strings?

Comment: @adiga why's that? O.o, but thanks :)

Comment: `x in y` checks if there is a `x` key in `y`. The keys of an array are it's indices. You need to use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: oh wow. i didnt know in checked the keys and not the values -.-

Comment: make sure that you declared `era` somewhere.